# vertical alignment with filling in Zurb Foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation, vertical-alignment

When I use the class vertical alignment, the right div is not as high as that of the left.
I would like to fill the black background only in the right div.

See the picture below -

[image]

My code -

```
    <div class="row expanded align-middle">
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 bg-verde" style="padding: 100px">
            <h4 class="">
                Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Nulla nec libero sit amet nulla efficitur bibendum vitae et purus.
                Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Nulla nec libero sit amet nulla efficitur bibendum vitae et purus.
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div class="small-12 medium-6 bg-black"  style="padding: 100px">
            <h4 class="color-white">
                Morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.
                Nulla nec libero sit amet nulla efficitur bibendum vitae et purus.
            </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the actual number of lines you have in each h4.
You can correct this using two techniques, using pure flex or using a jquery library. Personally, I prefer jquery library due to uncompatibilities of flex.

Here is a helpful site that can help you center in any manner:
http://howtocenterincss.com/

And here is the jQuery library I use:
http://brm.io/jquery-match-height-demo/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Foundation equalizer](http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/equalizer.html) for that. You just need to add data attributes to the conainer row and to each of the columns.

```
  <div class="row" data-equalizer data-equalize-on="medium">
     <div class="columns small-12 medium-6" data-equalizer-watch>
        ...
     </div>
     <div class="columns small-12 medium-6" data-equalizer-watch>
        ...
     </div>
</div>
```

Example in [this codepen](http://codepen.io/kemie/pen/OpYejr).